# What would pattern matching look like in a strict Haskell?

Tags: haskell

As a research experiment, I've recently worked on implementing strict-by-default Haskell modules. Instead of being lazy-by-default and having `!` as an escape hatch, we're strict-by-default and have `~` as an escape hatch. This behavior is enabled using a `{-# LANGUAGE Strict #-}` pragma.

While working on making patterns strict I came up on an interesting question: should patterns be strict in the "top-level" only or in all bind variables. For example, if we have

```
f x = case x of
  y -> ...
```

we will force `y` even though Haskell would not do so. The more tricky case is

```
f x = case x of
  Just y -> ...
```

Should we interpret that as

```
f x = case x of
  Just y -> ...  -- already strict in 'x' but not in `y`
```

or

```
f x = case x of
  Just !y -> ...  -- now also strict in 'y'
```

(Note that we're using the normal, lazy Haskell `Just` here.)

One design constraint that might of value is this: I want the pragma to be modular. For example, even with `Strict` turned on we don't evaluate arguments to functions defined *in other modules*. That would make it non-modular.

Is there any prior art here?

Comment: I don’t have prior art, but from your description of the language, I’d expect the latter (and write `Just ~y` if I want the other).

Comment: `case` is strict either way.

Comment: Perhaps you should view it differently: `Just` is strict by default in its first argument, so it doesn't matter whether case is strict or non-strict in variable bindings or wildcards.

Comment: To my eye, the first seems more reasonable because `Just` is defined lazily. If `Just` were defined in a `Strict` module then the second would be expected.

Comment: @Rhymoid I didn't mean for `Just` to be strict in its first argument. It's the normal Haskell `Just`, defined in a module that doesn't use the `Strict` pragma.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I understand things, refutable patterns are always strict at least on the outer level. Which is another way to say that the scrutinized expression must have been evaluated to WHNF, otherwise you couldn't see if it is a 'Just' or a 'Nothing'.

Hence your

```
!(Just y) -> ...
```

notation appears useless.

OTOH, since in a strict language, the argument to `Just` must already have been evaluated, the notation

```
Just !y ->
```

doesn't make sense either.

Comment: That's not the question.

Comment: Yes, I'll add something.

Comment: `!(Just x)` was a bad example. I intended to say that we will evaluate `x` in `let f x = ...` as well. Note I'm not talking about making the language strict overall, just on a per module basis. It's as if you'd put a bang on every argument and binding. The question is how deep the bangs go.

Comment: @tibbe Maybe you could make the depth configurable with a ghc cmdline argument or something? I'm not sure how such a pragma would affect programs on average depending on the depth, so leaving it as an argument could help during the experimentation phase.